# createUserWithEmailandPassword().addOnCompleteListener() won't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to working with firebase so I appreciate every help I get. I am trying to create an login and register activity. The problem is in my register activity when I try to sign up the user. The createUserWithEmailandPassword() and addOnCompleteListener() methodes won't work. I tried to check them in debbuger and it goes from mAuth.createUserWithEmailandPassword().addOnCompleteListener() to the end of the function and when I try to run it it shows me the toast message "Faild to register!". I think is the last toast. What should I do?

Update:
Now I get the message "user signed up succesfully", but there is still nothing in my firebase realtime database and authentication.

```
Registe Activity:

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText password, email, faculty, specialization, firstName, lastName;
    private Button signUp;
    private TextView existingUser;
    private ProgressBar progbar;
  //  private FirebaseDatabase firebaseUser;
     private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        signUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        existingUser = findViewById(R.id.AlreadyRegistered);
        password = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        email = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        faculty = findViewById(R.id.faculty);
        specialization = findViewById(R.id.specialization);
        firstName = findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        progbar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //Firebase tabela user
        //Creare si inserare user Adaugare user in firebase
        //Functie de salvare in FireBase

        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void registerUser(){
        String emailEt = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordEt = password.getText().toString().trim();
        String facultyEt = faculty.getText().toString().trim();
        String specializtionEt = specialization.getText().toString().trim();
        String firstNameEt = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastNameEt = lastName.getText().toString().trim();

//        if(firstNameEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(lastNameEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(passwordEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(facultyEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(specializtionEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(emailEt.isEmpty())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "This field is requried!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailEt).matches())
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Provide a valid email",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        if(passwordEt.length() < 6)
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Password should be at least 6 characters!",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //     progbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Verifica daca userul este deja inregistrat
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEt, passwordEt)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
              if(task.isSuccessful()){
                  User user = new User(lastNameEt, firstNameEt, facultyEt, specializtionEt, emailEt, passwordEt);

                  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                          .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                          .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                          if(task.isSuccessful()){
                              Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                       "User has been registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                          } else{
                              Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Faild to register!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          }
                      }
                  });
              } else{
                  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Faild to register!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
            }
        });
    }
}

build.gradle(:app)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.ase.proiect_draft"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //MAterial Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'

    //Rounded Image View
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    //Navigation Component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0-rc03'

    //DarkMode Theme
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm going to be blunt: NEVER store a user's unencrypted password in your database - even during testing. Remove it from your `User` class IMMEDIATELY. Firebase Authentication will handle the password for you safely and securely.

Comment: I suggest making your "This field is required!" messages more specific. Currently, any of those fields could be missing and your user wouldn't know which one. Use "Email is required!", "Faculty is required!" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be new to dealing with asynchronous APIs, so I'll first talk you through that, and then show you how to further troubleshoot this specific problem.

Firebase Authentication (like most modern cloud) APIs are asynchronous, since they require a call to the server and that may take some time. Instead of blocking the code, and keeping your user from interacting with your app, they allow the main code to continue, and then call your callback code once the server call is complete.

This is why the debugger "skips" over your `onComplete` call **initially**, at that point you're merely starting the call to the server. If you put a toast or `Log.i` right after the closing `}` of that entire code block, you'll see that it goes there right away.

To debug asynchronous callback, you need to put a breakpoint inside those callbacks, so on the first line of inside `onComplete`. If you do that and let the code run, your breakpoint will be hit when the server call has completed. At that point you can step through that code.

As said at the start, most modern web/cloud based API are based around such asynchronous calls, so learning how to debug these now will likely be very helpful going forward.

---

Now on to troubleshooting the actual problem. Since the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` failed, there's actually an exception in the task that you can inspect to figure out what went wrong. I typically throw that exception in my own code, but you can also pass it to `Log.e` to get it in the logcat output.

So:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEt, passwordEt)
        .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      if(task.isSuccessful()){
          User user = new User(lastNameEt, firstNameEt, facultyEt, specializtionEt, emailEt, passwordEt);

          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                  .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                  .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                  if(task.isSuccessful()){
                      Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                               "User has been registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                  } else{
                      // 
                      // | | |
                      // v v v   The next two lines are changed/new
                      // 
                      Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Failed to register: "+task.getException().getMessage()+"!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Log.e("Firebase", "Failed to register", task.getException());
                      progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  }
              }
          });
      } else{
          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Faild to register!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    }
});
```